# How can I put another text in a cell by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I would like to put the array price in the same cell of the array antipasti. I've tried too but I substituted the text. I would like to have all of two arrays in the same cell.
I didn't know how to do that. Can someone pls tell me how? Thank you so much

Here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwOkj.png

```
function generateTableAntipasti() {
//Build an array containing Customer records.
var antipasti = new Array();
antipasti.push(["Antipasti"]);
antipasti.push(["Patatine"]);
antipasti.push(["Kellogs"]);
antipasti.push(["Ciao"]);
antipasti.push(["Hello"]);
antipasti.push(["Bye"]);

var price = new Array();
price.push(["5,00$"]);
price.push(["5,00$"]);
price.push(["5,00$"]);
price.push(["5,00$"]);
price.push(["5,00$"]);
price.push(["5,00$"]);


//Create a HTML Table element.
var table = document.createElement("Table");
table.border = "1";
table.className = "Antipasti";
table.cellSpacing = 20;

//Add the data rows.
for (var i = 0; i < antipasti.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = antipasti[i];     
}

var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
dvTable.innerHTML = "";
dvTable.appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: Something like: `cell.innerHTML = antipasti[i]; + ' - ' + price[i];` ?

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, but if I would like to put below the array Antipasti?

Comment: Ok then try `+ '<br/>' + price[i];` or create whatever html structure you want within the cell

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks so much! Just last question. Is it possible to customise the br with css?

Comment: Sure you can use any html you want. A `<br/>` is just an html line break and not visible by default. Try a `<hr/>` instead for a visible horizontal line for example that can be styled. Or but name and price in separate `<div>` you can style by class names

Comment: You are slighly overcomplicating things too: Your `antipasti`-array will work just as well and will be easier to manage if you build it like `var antipasti = ["Antipasti","Patatine","Kellogs","Ciao","Hello","Bye"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above points put together and shortened a little bit ...

```js
function generateTableAntipasti() {
  //Build an array containing Customer records.
  var antipasti = ["Antipasti","Patatine","Kellogs","Ciao","Hello","Bye"], 
      price =     ["5,00$","5,00$","5,00$","5,00$","5,00$","5,00$"];

  //Create a HTML Table element.
  var table = document.createElement("Table");
  table.border = "1";
  table.className = "Antipasti";
  table.cellSpacing = 8;

//Add the data rows.
  antipasti.forEach((a,i)=>table.insertRow(-1).insertCell(-1).innerHTML = a +'<br>'+price[i]);

  var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
  dvTable.innerHTML = "";
  dvTable.appendChild(table);
}

generateTableAntipasti()
```

```html
<div id="dvTable"></div>
```